# Why would a static nested interface be used in Java?

Tags: java, interface, static

I have just found a static nested interface in our code-base.

```
class Foo {
    public static interface Bar {
        /* snip */
    }
    /* snip */
}
```

I have never seen this before. The original developer is out of reach. Therefore I have to ask SO:

What are the semantics behind a static interface? What would change, if I remove the `static`? Why would anyone do this?

Comment: This is not an 'inner interface: it is a *nested* interface. Inner has a specific meaning in Java.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The static keyword in the above example is redundant (a nested interface is automatically "static") and can be removed with no effect on semantics; I would recommend it be removed. The same goes for "public" on interface methods and "public final" on interface fields - the modifiers are redundant and just add clutter to the source code.

Either way, the developer is simply declaring an interface named Foo.Bar. There is no further association with the enclosing class, except that code which cannot access Foo will not be able to access Foo.Bar either. (From source code - bytecode or reflection can access Foo.Bar even if Foo is package-private!)

It is acceptable style to create a nested interface this way if you expect it to be used only from the outer class, so that you do not create a new top-level name. For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public interface Bar {
        void callback();
    }
    public static void registerCallback(Bar bar) {...}
}
// ...elsewhere...
Foo.registerCallback(new Foo.Bar() {
    public void callback() {...}
});
```

Comment: In Jesse Glick's answer, what this mean: (From source code - bytecode or reflection can access Foo.Bar even if Foo is package-private!).

Comment: Kaillash, private methods can be accessed through relfection (in the reflect package) and through directly accessing the bytecode of the generated .class files.

Comment: By "bytecode ... can access Foo.Bar" I mean that a compiled class referencing Foo.Bar can be loaded and run even if it could not reference Foo. This might happen if the class were compiled at an earlier time when Foo were public, or if the class were hand-assembled or compiled from some non-Java language, etc. The Java compiler, however, checks the access modifier on the enclosing class even when the resulting bytecode would not refer to that enclosing class.

Comment: On line 3, would it be: "public final" on interface fields  -> "public **static** final" on interface fields?

Comment: @Raining It should be `public static final` since `interface` can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 79):

The question has been answered, but one good reason to use a nested interface is if its function is directly related to the class it is in. A good example of this is a `Listener`. If you had a class `Foo` and you wanted other classes to be able to listen for events on it, you could declare an interface named `FooListener`, which is ok, but it would probably be more clear to declare a nested interface and have those other classes implement `Foo.Listener` (a nested class `Foo.Event` isn't bad along with this).

Comment: A typical example is `java.util.Map.Entry` (which is an interface nested in another interface).

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I would prefer the outer class to be in it's own package and any supplementary interfaces (e.g. `Map.Entry`) or classes to also be within that package. I say this because I like to keep my classes short and to the point. Also a reader can see what other entities are related to a class by looking at the classes in the package. I'd probably have a package `java.collections.map` for maps. This is about OO and modularity. `java.util` has too much in it. `util` is like `common` - a smell IMO

Comment: @Shaggy: `java.util` certainly does have too much in it. That said, I don't think that breaking it down into such fine-grained packages as you're suggesting is ideal either.

Comment: @DavidKerr Suppose you call this interface `java.util.MapEntry` outside its own package. First reflex : what are the interface related to this class ? I look into the class. Unless javadoc links to this interface, I have no clue of their relation. 
Plus people don't look at the import package .
Everyone has own opinions. No one is right, no one is wrong

Comment: @RaymondChenon part of what I said was to put Map and its associated classes, e.g. Map.Entry into a separate package, e.g java.collections.map. That way all code related to the map is in a single location (the package) and the top-level Map class is not burdened. I'd maybe put the related implementations (HashMap, etc) in the same package.

Comment: This is not an 'inner interface': it is a nested interface. Inner has a specific meaning in Java.

Answer (score 15):

Member interfaces are implicitly static. The static modifier in your example can be removed without changing the semantics of the code. See also the the Java Language Specification [8.5.1. Static Member Type Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)

Comment: This is not an 'inner interface': it is a nested interface. Inner has a specific meaning in Java.

Comment: @EJP , I read various blogs using the terms interchangeably. Do inner interface exists ? How they are different from nested interface ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin , Nested interface means static. There exists inner class and nested class , but not inner interface. Even if so , It should be called as nested interface.  Inner - non static and nested is static.

Answer (score 9):

An inner interface has to be static in order to be accessed. The interface isn't associated with instances of the class, but with the class itself, so it would be accessed with `Foo.Bar`, like so:

```
public class Baz implements Foo.Bar {
   ...
}
```

In most ways, this isn't different from a static inner class.

Comment: A nested interface is automatically static, whether one writes the keyword or not.

Comment: We really need a way for the community to vote to accept a different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/74400/632951

Comment: ['Static inner' is a contradiction in terms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: @ClintonN.Dreisbach Can you explain what is meant by `The interface isn't associated with instances of the class, but with the class itself` more further, I did n't get it

Answer (score 6):

Jesse's answer is close, but I think that there is a better code to demonstrate why an inner interface may be useful. Look at the code below before you read on. Can you find why the inner interface is useful? The answer is that class DoSomethingAlready can be instantiated with **any** class that implements A and C; not just the concrete class Zoo. Of course, this can be achieved even if AC is not inner, but imagine concatenating longer names (not just A and C), and doing this for other combinations (say, A and B, C and B, etc.) and you easily see how things go out of control. Not to mention that people reviewing your source tree will be overwhelmed by interfaces that are meaningful only in one class.So to summarize,  *an inner interface enables the construction of custom types and improves their encapsulation*.

```
class ConcreteA implements A {
 :
}

class ConcreteB implements B {
 :
}

class ConcreteC implements C {
 :
}

class Zoo implements A, C {
 :
}

class DoSomethingAlready {
  interface AC extends A, C { }

  private final AC ac;

  DoSomethingAlready(AC ac) {
    this.ac = ac;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nonsense. The class `Zoo` does *not* implement the interface `AC`, therefore, instances of `Zoo` can not be passed to the constructor of `DoSomethingAlready` which expects `AC`. The fact that `AC` extends both, `A` and `C`, does not imply that classes implementing `A` and `C` magically also implement `AC`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question very directly, look at Map.Entry.

[Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

also this may be useful

[Static Nested Inerfaces blog Entry](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/06/static-nested-interfaces/)

Comment: This is an example, but not really an answer.

Comment: I use Map.Entry to create "Pair" objects a lot. It's exposed. The implementation of Pair has two schools of thoughts, but that isn't the point here. Map.Entry might be inner but I use it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I see static inner classes. Static inner classes cannot reference the containing classes wherease non-static classes can. Unless you're running into some package collisions (there already is an interface called Bar in the same package as Foo) I think I'd make it it's own file. It could also be a design decision to enforce the logical connection between Foo and Bar. Perhaps the author intended Bar to only be used with Foo (though a static inner interface won't enforce this, just a logical connection)

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms. Nested classes are *either* static or inner.

Answer (score 0):

If you will change class Foo into interface Foo the "public" keyword in the above example will be also redundant as well because

> interface defined inside another interface will **implicitly public
>   static.**

Comment: Didn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

In 1998, Philip Wadler suggested a difference between static interfaces and non-static interfaces.

> So far as I can see, the only difference in making an
>   interface non-static is that it can now include non-static inner
>   classes; so the change would not render invalid any existing Java
>   programs.

For example, he proposed a solution to the [Expression Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), which is the mismatch between expression as "how much can your language express" on the one hand and expression as "the terms you are trying to represent in your language" on the other hand.

An example of the difference between static and non-static nested interfaces can be seen in [his sample code](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/expression/expression.txt):

```
// This code does NOT compile
class LangF<This extends LangF<This>> {
    interface Visitor<R> {
        public R forNum(int n);
    }

    interface Exp {
        // since Exp is non-static, it can refer to the type bound to This
        public <R> R visit(This.Visitor<R> v);
    }
}
```

His suggestion never made it in Java 1.5.0. Hence, all other answers are correct: there is no difference to static and non-static nested interfaces.

Comment: It should be noted that all this refers to GJ which was a very early processor for generics in Java.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, the static interface/class allows the interface/class to be used like a top-level class, that is, it can be declared by other classes. So, you can do:

```
class Bob
{
  void FuncA ()
  {
    Foo.Bar foobar;
  }
}
```

Without the static, the above would fail to compile. The advantage to this is that you don't need a new source file just to declare the interface. It also visually associates the interface Bar to the class Foo since you have to write Foo.Bar and implies that the Foo class does something with instances of Foo.Bar.

[A description of class types in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html).

Comment: Without the static it *does* compile. The 'static' is redundant.

Comment: @EJP: According to that article I linked to, without the static the inner class can only be used by the owning class and not by anything outside the owing class. The static makes it a nested top level class and can be used by objects outside the scope of the owning class (at least, according to the article). The static is not entirely redundant and affects the scope of the inner class. This applies to classes, interfaces may always act like top level objects (need to read the language spec to check). Perhaps I should have separated the interface and class parts of my answer (my bad).

Answer (score -6):

Static means that any class part of the package(project) can acces it without using a pointer. This can be usefull or hindering depending on the situation.

The perfect example of the usefullnes of "static" methods is the Math class. All methods in Math are static. This means you don't have to go out of your way, make a new instance, declare variables and store them in even more variables, you can just enter your data and get a result.

Static isn't always that usefull. If you're doing case-comparison for instance, you might want to store data in several different ways. You can't create three static methods with identical signatures. You need 3 different instances, non-static, and then you can and compare, caus if it's static, the data won't change along with the input.

Static methods are good for one-time returns and quick calculations or easy obtained data.

Comment: I know what static means. I just have never ever seen it on an interface before. Therefore your question is off-topic - sorry

Comment: I think his answer is off-topic.