# Java Generics: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, generics

```
interface A<T> {

    interface B {
       // Results in non-static type variable T cannot
       // be referenced from a static context
       T foo(); 
    }

}
```

Is there anyway round this? Why is T seen as static when referenced from A.B?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/74400/697449

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All member fields of an interface are by default `public`, `static` and `final`.

Since inner interface is `static` by default, you can't refer to `T` from static fields or methods.

Because `T` is actually associated with an instance of a class, if it were associated with a static field or method which is associated with class then it wouldn't make any sense

Comment: Thanks, that answers the first part of the question. How do I get the type T seen in the inner interface to be the same type at that of the containing interface?

Comment: I would remove the first sentence as it's unnecessary and misleading - yes interface fields are implicitly `public static final` but this has to do with interface *methods* which are implicitly `public abstract`. The fact that inner interfaces are implicitly `static` themselves is what's important.

Comment: well inner interface is same as inner field

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this.

```
public interface A<T> {

     interface B<T> extends A<T>{

       T foo(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner interface doesn't know what T is. Try this.

```
interface A<T> {

    interface B<T> {
       T foo(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't the T in B<T> a different T than in A<T> here?