# Why can't I use generics in an inner interface?

Tags: java, static

I tried to compile the following code:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public interface Bar {
        public void bar(T t);
    }

    void foo(T t);
}
```

But I get this error: "Foo.this cannot be referenced from a static context."

Specifically, I get it on the "T" in bar(T t). However foo(T t) does not produce the same error. I don't understand why that's a static context and what the error really means.

Comment: Similar with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963601/java-generics-non-static-type-variable-t-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-con

Comment: `public interface Bar<T> {`

Comment: @brso05 this would redefine `T` rather than reuse it, so `T` might have a different value which I assume is not what the OP intends.

Comment: @Thomas unless you redefine it with the same class...

Comment: @brso05 of course but the compiler would still treat both `T`'s as having potentially different values - it's still parameter shadowing/hiding.

Comment: @Thomas yes that is correct.

Comment: @brso05 I'm tempted to use it anyway...

Comment: @BarryFruitman it should work just be careful when you use it...

Comment: @BarryFruitman I'd probably use a different name for the inner `T` so that you see the difference the compiler sees. Hiding the outer `T` might cause hard to track bugs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "nested" interface (Bar in your example) is implicitly static. So it can't access instance specific information related to Foo, such as its generic type.

See for example [JLS #8.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> A member interface is implicitly static