# java This cannot be referenced from a static context cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, generics, abstraction

i tried to abstract my code a little bit and i got over a error i dont know to handle

```
public interface Manager<T extends Member> {
    Set<T> member = new HashSet<>();

    default Member getMember(String name){
        for(T m : member){
            if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                return m;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

now when i hover over the T in Set i get "Manager.this cannot be referenced from a static context". i really have no clue why.

Comment: fields in an interface are static by default

Comment: A better duplicate: [Java Generics: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963601/java-generics-non-static-type-variable-t-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-con)

Comment: `member` is implicitly `public static final`. The `static` part means `T` (as a type param for instance members) can't be used in the field declaration.