# Why can't my class implement an interface declared inside it?

Tags: java, interface, implementation, inner-classes

I just encountered a behavior I first thought it was a bug in Eclipse. Consider this simple class:

```
public class Foo {
    public static interface Callback {
        public void onAction();
    }
}
```

This is perfectly valid. However, this isn't:

```
public class Foo implements Callback {
    public static interface Callback {
        public void onAction();
    }

    public void onAction() { /*some implementation*/ }
}
```

But this is valid, too:

```
public class Foo {
    public static interface Callback {
        public void onAction();
    }

    private final Callback mCallback = new Callback() {
        public void onAction() { /*some implementation*/ }
    };
}
```

Why does Java force me to kind of 'waste' a member for it, if it could simply save it by letting me implement this itself? I'm well aware of the 'workaround' to put this interface in its own file, but out of curiosity: Is there a reason why this won't work?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do a new on an interface, so new Callback() is invalid

Comment: I'm not sure of the official rationale for this not working, but I don't see any reason why you would want to have a class implement an interface which it contains -- why wouldn't you just define the class with the methods you're trying to put into the interface? Why do you want an interface at all in this case?

Comment: @MiguelPrz he's creating an implementation of the interface inline using `{}`

Comment: @MiguelPrz Actually, that's instantiating an anonymous class which implements `Callback`. It is valid, and can be useful.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java) has some good explanation on inner interfaces and their semantics.

Comment: Does `implements Foo.Callback` work? I don't think you're in the scope of `Foo` at that point. This area is mucky. IIRC, in the early days it wasn't well defined, with javac getting updates to cover more cases. IMO, most of this stuff should have been outlawed because there are lots of corner cases and it isn't something you'd want to see in real code.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, no unfortunatly it doesn't work to declare `Foo.Callback` @iamnotmaynard because my class is holding in fact a List of those Callbacks. It should get triggered first, and then dispatch it to the others...

Comment: @sbk thanks, good point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your 2nd case, since the signatures are checked before the bodies of the classes, when the compiler tries to compile the `Foo` class, the `Callback` interface isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 8):

Using this code

```
public class Foo implements Callback{

public static interface Callback{
    public void onAction()
}

public void onAction(){//some implementation}
}
```

what is `Callback` ? The compiler (btw which is different from `Eclipse`, ) doesn't know what is `Callback`.

You defined the `Callback` interface after you used it.

Comment: can't the compiler look ahead and get a list of all classes to come ?! feels kinda silly

Comment: It is an unfortunate statement, in Java language textually "before" and "after" is not relevant as in some other languages.
Here "before" and "after" should be read as "as the compiler can reach it". The compiler first try to compile the class header, then the class body (maybe for eliminating the opportunity of recoursive definition checks...) - thus in the header you can't use a definition what reside in the body.