# Is it at all acceptable to have nested public interfaces?

Tags: java

I have several interfaces all with only a single method and they are all very similar. I know it works, but should I or should I not group them like this:

```
public class InterfaceGroup {
    public interface Type1 {
        public void method(int a);
    }
    public interface Type2 {
        public void method(String s);
    }
    public interface Type3 {
        public void method();
    }
}
```

And then reference them externally as `InterfaceGroup.Type1`.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your intention is but in general this looks fishy to me. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Having many 3 line interfaces / files.

Comment: Also `InterfaceGroup` has no other function other than grouping them.

Comment: why don't you use a package for just grouping? whats wrong with tiny classes/interfaces if they have a very specific and focused purpose?

Comment: Actually ended up just making them private as I realised I was only using them internally. But otherwise yes, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is sometimes helpful to have such a design. For example, it is the choice for `Map.Entry` in Java standard library.

The blemish on such a design, though, is that you define a type that doesn't play the role of a type, and it is actually never appropriate to implement it. If I found out that in a library I use such a type exists for no other reason than to reduce the number of source code files, I'd be at least slightly annoyed :-) On the other hand, when I'm writing code whose scope of visibility is just within  the implementation, I use such tricks  remorselessly.

Comment: there is no grouping of multiple interfaces in Map, only one nested interface

Comment: @lbalazscs I see this as close enough to establish an analogy.

Comment: @lbalazscs My bad, I wrote too fast, I just checked and you're right.

Comment: I think the analogy is not strong. The `Map` interface is a real interface, not merely a container for other interfaces. `Map.Entry` is a type used by several of `Map`s methods, and it has little meaning outside the context of a `Map`. This is not the case in the OP's proposal.

Comment: @arend OP: "Is it at all acceptable to have nested public interfaces?" Me: yes, see for example Map.Entry

Comment: @Marko You're right of course, having nested interfaces can make a lot of sense - but I have yet to see a good example where the outer type is not itself expected to be instantiated, which is what OP seems to be asking about.

Comment: @arend As you were writing your comment, I was expanding my answer with the same thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought `TimeUnit` had that too but they are enumerations, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java) that could maybe explain why it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason against this, but I'm not sure this makes for understandable code. Programmers will typically expect that an interface is there to be implemented, which is not the case in your proposition.

Note that the number of source files may be smaller this way, but the number of class files will be larger, as both `InterfaceGroup` and all its nested types will be compiled to a separate class file.