# What is the use of nested interfaces in this code

Tags: java

I have gone through the following link [Why would a static nested interface be used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java).

In my code base I have:

```
public interface I1{

   public static interface I2 {
        public void doSomething();
   }

    //some other methods

    public void myMethod(I2 myObject); 
}
```

And in some other class in a different package :

```
public abstract class SomeClass implements I2{
   //mandatory method...
}
```

Now, my question is - "Is it really a good design to put `I2` in `I1`"?

EDIT :

```
public interface XClientSession {
static public interface OnQueryResultSentListener {

        public void onQueryResultSent(XQueryResult result);
    }
 public void setOnQueryResultSentListener(OnQueryResultSentListener listener);

}
```

/ And in a different file I have...

```
 public abstract class XAppAgentBase extends IntentService 
    implements XClient, OnQueryResultSentListener {
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure SomeClass implements "I2"? I would expect it to have to implement "I1.I2" to reference the inner interface.

Comment: @TheLostMind Instead of paraphrasing your code, can you show the actual names of the interfaces and methods?  That might make the question (and answers) more relevant.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - SomeClass implements Only I2... not I1.I2... I2 can be accessed directly (without I1..)

Comment: @TheLostMind In this case, it makes sense, because `OnQueryResultSentListener`s will only ever be used by classes that implement `XClientSession`.  It can be used to shown a relationship between the two, and you're not likely to ever need an `OnQueryResultSentListener` without an `XClientSession`.

Comment: @mrjink - XAppAgentBase  doesnt implement XClientSession.. it implements XClient..

Comment: `XAppAgentBase` cannot implement `OnQueryResultSentListener`. It can implement `XClientSession.OnQueryResultSentListener`.

Comment: @TheLostMind Ok, so then don't?  If the `OnQueryResultSentListener` is used in more places, it should maybe be an interface on its own.

Comment: Check your codebase. If the code you have posted is correct then your codebase also has a `OnQueryResultSentListener` interface as a top level interface.

Comment: Here is the example : [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use static keyword for inner interface as interface declared inside an interface is by default static similar to saying variables defined in interfaces are be default public and static.

Is it a good design? - Depends on the design for which it is created for. Your code constrains accessibility of I2 interface to only those part of codes that have accessible to I1 Interface.

Comment: Yes.. I know that static is redundant.. And I also know that its valid.. My point is - is it good?.. Can it cause any problems in the future?. Can it break the code/design in the future?

Answer (score 0):

In java it is absolutely valid to define an interface within another

It is a coding style to say Interface `I2` exists to be used in `I1` (or they are related with each other)

Comment: My question is : "is keeping I2 in I1" an advantage in my specific case?. Is it a good design?. I know its valid..