# Java inner and nested classes

Tags: java, class

I've started preparing myself for the OCJP7 exam and I found this chapter that seems to be very complicated.

Let's say I have this code:

```
class Outer1{
    interface InnerInterface{
        String x = "test";
    }
    class InnerClass{
        String x = "test";
    }
}
class Outer2{
    static interface NestedInterface{
        String x = "test";
    }
    static class NestedClass{
        String x = "test";
    }
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String s1 = Outer1.InnerInterface.x;
        String s2 = new Outer1().new InnerClass().x;
        String s3 = Outer2.NestedInterface.x;
        String s4 = new Outer2.NestedClass().x;
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why we can access `Outer1.InnerInterface.x` and `Outer2.NestedInterface.x` in the same manner? Inner interfaces are static by default? I'm trying to make some connections to make them more clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a static inner interface be used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Oracle's Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) :

> A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested
> classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing
> class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not
> have access to other members of the enclosing class. As a member of
> the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared private, public,
> protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be
> declared public or package private.)

Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Thus they only make sense as static. Declaring a nested interface as static is redundant.

Also, the exercise uses confusing names for the interfaces.
Both `InnerClass` and `NestedClass` are nested classes. But only `InnerClass` is an inner class since "inner class" means "non-static nested class".
Similarly one might expect `InnerInterface` to be an "inner interface" meaning "non-static nested interface"; but such a thing does not exist. Both `InnerInterface` and `NestedInterface` are nested interfaces and none of them are inner interfaces.

Comment: Not sure why you quote this part from the Java Tutorial, as it talks about classes, and the question is about interfaces. The naming of this exercise is not only confusing but plain wrong, because there is no such thing as an Inner Interface. The only type of nested interface that exists is the member interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html

Comment: The tittle of the question is "Java inner and nested classes". And the code mentions both interfaces and classes. I consider the question to be abouth both nested/inner clases and nested/inner interfaces. And about what difference there are between them. The difference (besides those between classes and interfaces in general) being that inner classes do exist and inner interfaces don't, as you say in your commend and I do in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, nested interfaces are implicitly `static`.  [Section 8.5.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1) states:

> A member interface is implicitly `static` (§9.1.1). It is permitted for the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the `static` modifier.

Because of this, you can access `x` through the nested interface in the same manner through outer classes `Outer1` and `Outer2` -- both nested interfaces, `InnerInterface` and `NestedInterface` are `static`.

Answer (score 3):

> *Could you tell me why we can access `Outer1.InnerInterface.x` and `Outer2.NestedInterface.x` in the same manner?*

Because they're both `static` fields.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3), Chapter 9. Interfaces, point 9.3 Field (Constant) Declarations:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   `public`, `static`, and `final`.

---

> *Inner interfaces are static by default?*

Yes.

From [8.1.3 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Member interfaces (§8.5) are implicitly `static` so they are never
>   considered to be inner classes.

Comment: Yes, I know that fields of an interface are static, but I didn't know that an interface declared within a class is static. I've finished  the chapter and I didn't find an answer... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The keyword `static` for nested interfaces is unnecessary and redundant. A nested interface is always static.

From a logical point of view it also makes no sense that a interface definition is bound to a specific instance of the outer class.